# Is there a "convolution" of asymptotic growth?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, asymptotics

Suppose that I have two asymptotic counts given by
$$
\#\{x \in [0,H] \cap \mathbb Z: f(x) \leq H\} \sim F(H)
$$
and also
$$
\#\{x \in [0,H] \cap \mathbb Z: g(x) \leq H\} \sim G(H).
$$

From these two counts, is there any way to deduce the asymptotic growth of
$$
\#\{x \in [0,H] \cap \mathbb Z: f(x) + g(x) \leq H\}?
$$

It seems that there are some ways to approximate this if $f, g$ are arithmetic functions, and in theory it seems to me that the answer should in some way be related to the convolution of $F(H)$ and $G(H)$, but I don't readily see it.

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Comment: @GHfromMO I learned from your answer, but it's not the answer that I was looking for (I was looking for the right conditions on $f$ and $g$ so that some type of convolution would work, rather than a pathology) so I'm going to keep the question open in case someone else comes along. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I think that $f$ and $g$ have to be very regular for a positive answer, and natural arithmetic functions (like multiplicative functions) are not like that.

Answer (score 8):

$F(H)$ and $G(H)$ do not determine the asymptotic growth of the third display. Indeed, consider the following two functions from $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$:
$$
f(x):=\begin{cases}0,&\text{$x$ is even;}\\x^2,&\text{$x$ is odd;}\end{cases}\qquad\qquad
g(x):=\begin{cases}x^2,&\text{$x$ is even;}\\0,&\text{$x$ is odd;}\end{cases}$$
Then
\begin{align*}
\#\{x \in [0,H]: f(x) \leq H\}& \sim H/2,\\
\#\{x \in [0,H]: g(x) \leq H\}& \sim H/2,
\end{align*}
but
\begin{align*}
\#\{x \in [0,H]: f(x)+g(x) \leq H\}& \sim \sqrt{H},\\
\#\{x \in [0,H]: f(x)+f(x) \leq H\}& \sim H/2.
\end{align*}

Comment: I was wondering if a counterexample along these lines are possible. Things might go better if you ask for $f$ and $g$ to be monotonic?

Comment: Thank you for this example! Of course, the setting that I had in mind is more natural, like what @QiaochuYuan suggested. Do you think that under some nice hypothesis, one could write down a convolution-type formula? (But don't assume that f and g are arithmetic, as that is already known!)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Under extra hypotheses things might go better, but my feeling is that monotonicity will not be enough.